# Font on the server doesn't show on local HTML file

Tags: html, css

I put the ttf font file on the server and used the following code in CSS

```
@font-face {  
   font-family: "fontname";  
   src: url("http://www.mywebsite.com/Fonts/fontname.ttf");
}

body {
  font-family: "fontname", sans-serif;
}
```

In the local HTML file I wrote:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssfile.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        body
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried different ttf files on the server but none of them worked. But if I put the font in the same directory as the HTML file on the computer it shows up. Does anyone know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any console errors in the browser? There may be a cross site scripting issue at play.

Here's an article about cross-domain fonts if so which should explain in more detail. Basically, your webserver needs to add this header to the font response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

http://davidwalsh.name/cdn-fonts